# Working out which cell Vlookup refers to

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

say if I see this Vlookup formula in my Excel spreadsheet:

```
=VLOOKUP(G37,'tb 2008'!$H$142:$M$247,6,FALSE)
```

Then is there an efficient way to find out which *cell* it is referencing? I don't want to manually perform the Vlookup in my head to find out which cell it found that fits the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about a nice way to do it, but you can just fill a column (for example, column N) with row numbers and then use two VLOOKUPs to get you the value from column 6 as well as the row number from column 7. Then you have the cell, it's M# where # is whatever is returned by the second VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 2):

=ADDRESS(
ROW((INDEX('tb2008'!$H$142:$H$247,MATCH(G37,'tb2008'!$L$142:$L$247,0)))),
COLUMN((INDEX('tb2008'!$H$142:$H$247,MATCH(G37,'tb2008'!$L$142:$L$247,0))))
)

match returns the number of an element in an array, eg (assume the range A1:A5 is filled with A,B,C,D,E:
 match(C,A1:A5,0) = 3

index will return a reference to a cell based on an row and column number.
 index(A1:A5, 0, 3) = C

and then we use the ROW and COLUMN functions to get the row and column address of that reference.
then put that together using ADDRESS

Answer (score 1):

By Which cell if you mean the Address of the Cell, you can use Index/Match and Index can be made to return a reference instead of the value

Comment: Yes, how do I use Index/Match?

Comment: look at the answer i posted for an explaination.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built in way of finding the cell.

Answer (score 0):

For this `VLOOKUP` of yours in particular.

```
=VLOOKUP(G37,'tb 2008'!$H$142:$M$247,6,FALSE)
```

you should get the info you need with this:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(G37;H142:H247;0);1)
```

G37 = the cell/value you are searching for (in this case a cell reference is of more practical use)

H142:H247 = column range with your search values. In case you the whole column is dedicated for the criteria, you can set (in this example) H:H

Hope this helps.